# MVC Razor- dropdown

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one dropdown on view that i have binded with model property. 
but I want to populate data on selection change of another dropdown using angularjs.

Sample
parent dropdown

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectName, Model.ProjectList, "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlWorkProject", @class = "width100", @ng_change = "getFSName()", @ng_model = "ddlWorkProject" })
```

child dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FSname, Model.FSList, "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlFSName", @class = "width100", @ng_model = "FSname1", @ng_options = "act.Value as act.Name for act in FSname" })
```

javascript code to populate data into dropdown

```
 $scope.getFSName = function () {
    projectStatusModuleService.getFSName($scope.ddlWorkProject).then(function (fs) {
        $scope.FSname = fs.data;
        // return JSON.stringify(fs.data);
        //$scope.FSname = "Writing code"; 
    });

};
```

But when i submit page, i am not getting selected item value on server.

Comment: Sounds like you should have the other dropdown in a partial view that loads every time you change the value of the first dropdown.

Comment: not sure if this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411983/mvc-3-binding-dynamic-view-data-to-model